# Datanucleus JDO with SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite, junit, jdo, datanucleus

For JUnit tests in our application, I'm attempting to initialize Datanucleus to use an SQLite database. However, when I try to get a `PersistenceManager` it fails while trying to create a `DELETEME********` table (I'm not fully aware WHY it needs this table yet, either).

It appears to be failing during truncate() because of some identifier length issue. I have attempted to tweak all sorts of various datanucleus configuration properties to no avail.

Can anyone explain to me why Datanucleus feels the need to create these `DELETEME****` tables, and what might potentially cause this truncation failure with a SQLite (org.sqlite.JDBC) database and not with MySQL?

---

Log:

```
Apr 12, 2011 1:30:16 PM org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.table.AbstractTable create
INFO: Creating table DELETEME1302640216142
Apr 12, 2011 1:32:10 PM org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager <init>
SEVERE: Failed initialising database. Please check that your database JDBC driver is accessible, and the database URL and username/password are correct. Exception : The length argument (=-3) is less than HASH_LENGTH(=4)!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The length argument (=-3) is less than HASH_LENGTH(=4)!
```

Full stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The length argument (=-3) is less than HASH_LENGTH(=4)!
    at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.identifier.AbstractIdentifierFactory.truncate(AbstractIdentifierFactory.java:314)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.identifier.AbstractIdentifierFactory.newPrimaryKeyIdentifier(AbstractIdentifierFactory.java:661)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.key.PrimaryKey.<init>(PrimaryKey.java:37)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.table.TableImpl.getPrimaryKey(TableImpl.java:128)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.table.TableImpl.getSQLCreateStatements(TableImpl.java:1264)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.table.AbstractTable.create(AbstractTable.java:419)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.initialiseSchema(RDBMSStoreManager.java:676)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.<init>(RDBMSStoreManager.java:350)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:597)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:300)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerFactoryImpl.initialiseStoreManager(ObjectManagerFactoryImpl.java:227)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:591)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:293)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:189)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
```

Comment: You might get an answer faster in the [datanucleus forum](http://www.datanucleus.org/servlet/forum/index)